# Graphical solution of LOP with three variables and a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

For what values of $\lambda$ does the following linear optimization problem has no solution?
$$
 x_2 - \lambda x_3 \to \operatorname{min}
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
 -x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 & ~=~ 3 \\
 -x_1 +  x_2       & ~\le~ 4 \\
               x_i & ~\ge~ 0, \quad i = 1,2,3
\end{align*}
Solve this graphically! (in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

I drawed an area of admissable solutions for different, fixed values of $x_1$ and came to the conclusion that it is always solvable, regardless of the values of $\lambda$ because the two restrictions always have a nonempty region of admissable solutions. Is this correct that it's solvable for all $\lambda$? But that makes this exercise quite trivial...

EDIT: It's $x_2$!

Comment: Your function to be minimized has no subscript on the $x$ in $x-\lambda x_3$. But that subscript should be 1 or 2, and without knowing which the solution differs.

Answer (score 1):

Having a nonempty region of admissible $x$ is necessary for existence of minimum. But it's not sufficient. The solution will also fail to exist if the function $x_2-\lambda x_3$ is not bounded from below on the admissible region.

To make the problem two-dimensions, you can eliminate $x_1$ from it, replacing it by $3x_2+x_3+3$. The constraints become
$$ 
\begin{align*}
 -x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 & ~=~ 3 \\
 -2x_2-x_3    & ~\le~ 7 \\
3x_2+x_3& ~\ge -3  \\
               x_i & ~\ge~ 0, \quad i = 2,3
\end{align*}
$$ 
After drawing the region, you should determine whether or not it is

- empty (if so, there is no solution)
- nonempty and bounded (if so, there is a solution)
- unbounded (then there is a solution if and only if the region does not contain any half-line with the direction vector $(-1,\lambda)$)